# onebox image broken for blog.stackoverflow.com

Tags: bug, chat, blog, onebox

When oneboxing a blog post from https://blog.stackoverflow.com/, the image source is missing the domain, and thus showing a broken image.

For example in [this message](//chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5285308#5285308):

> [image]

And the cause is this image source:

> [image]

As you can see, the domain is missing. (i.e. correct source is https://blog.stackoverflow.com/images/wordpress/jeopardy-set1.jpg)